# How can I upload base64 to s3 directly with base64-arraybuffer from react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, amazon-s3, base64

I'm trying to upload base64 image to s3 bucket with only base64 string. I don't want to save file but I was able to get base64 string.
Previously, I 've used

```
  const arrayBuffer = decode(base64);
```

Which worked fine when I had uri which was from local file. But I tried passing base64 string directly to decode from base64-array as above skipping readFile function, it is uploading broken file. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: see this can help you https://github.com/aviboy2006/aws-s3-file-upload-progress

Comment: Did you get solution for this ? If yes then please update